# ibm content navigator System Administrator has no access to Data Management desktop

Tags: filenet, ibm-content-navigator

Hey guys i got a big headache.
By mistake a user logged with the only one account with admin privileges into Content Navigator(Filenet) and did the following actions:
Desktop Data Management > Section Authentication >
Limit access to especific users and groups > choose Enable
and click on Save and close

While trying to log on again in Content Navigator 
Appears a message "Your System Administrator has no access to Data Management desktop"
Ask your Administrator to add you to the list of users who have accessto the Data Management Desktop CIWEB1037

We are using IBM Websphere Application Server V8.5, IBM FileNet Content Engine V5.2 and
IBM Content Navigator 2.02 running on Suse Enterprise 11

Is there a file on which can add privileges to the admin user to fix the access to content?
Please help us. Thanxs in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into the admin console directly using your administrator account:

http(s)://HOSTNAME:PORT/navigator/?desktop=admin

This will bypass the default desktop and get you into the controls again. You should be able to adjust the permissions back from there.

Note: the admin desktop for ICN has known issues when running in a browser that is launched with RunAs. It works best if you log into the machine with the admin account directly and launch the browser as normally that way.

Comment: Thank you very much! it works great and we recover the admin account.